# Make submit button inactive until fields have been filled

Tags: jquery

I'm using RSForms! Pro and I have a form which has 4 fields which need to be completed. Is there any way to set the Submit button to not be active until all of the fields have been completed?

I have tried the following but it's not working correctly:

```
function validate(){
    if ($('#FullName').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#Email').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#VenueName').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#VenuePostcode').val().length    >   0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Are you looking for RS Forms Pro configuration solution or to write your own server side validation code to implement?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ideally looking for any solution. I've tried the above function using JavaScript but it doesn't appear to work

Comment: Honestly, this is something I would try to do using RS Forms back-end interface.  I'm fairly confident they have a solid client-side verification feature set and there's no need to re-invent the wheel if you're already using the component.

Comment: Turn on AJAX Validation and set all fields required. This will block submitting an empty form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you start with disabling the submit button using jQuery(to avoid disabled buttons for non-javascript users):

```
jQuery("#Submit").prop('disabled', true);
```

Then use this code to enable the submit button if all fields are filled out:

```
var toValidate = jQuery('#FullName, #Email, #VenueName, #VenuePostcode'),
    valid = false;
toValidate.keyup(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
    } else {
        jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
    }
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    if (valid === true) {
        jQuery("#Submit").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        jQuery("#Submit").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

<sup>Modified code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761696/disable-submit-button-until-input-fields-filled-in) on StackOverflow.</sup>

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxqu7yy/

Comment: +1, however I would remove `onfocus="this.value=''"` from the inputs as if you type in a value, then go back to it, it gets reset. I would also suggest making `jQuery(this)` and `jQuery("#Submit")` variables as you're using them more than once ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the code can be improved. I couldn't get the variables to work right now, maybe tomorrow... Regarding the `onFocus` code, that was from the OPs website (I think), but a better solution would probably be to use `placeholder="Full name"`. Example: `<input type="text" size="20" id="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" />`

Comment: Use `.change()` instead of `.keyup()` because some people use auto-form-filler plugins or copy/paste with right click.